# Is there a way to paginate Django's admin page that uses the django-nested-admin lib?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-pagination, django-nested-admin

I have an admin page using NedstedStackedInLine, and the problem is that in the inside model, i have to many occurrences of the secondary model. Is there a way to paginate the inside models to not cause 502 error when the users tryng to access the page in a production scenario. Running localy the page is loaded, but with many seconds because of the large amount of occurences?

Here is the code to ilustrate the problem.

```
class CityInlineAdmin(NestedStackedInline):
    model = City
    

class NestedStateAdmin(NestedStackedInline):
    model = State
    inlines = (CityInlineAdmin,)


class CountryAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = (NestedStateAdmin,)
```

I have already tried the django-admin-inline-paginator, but appears that this lib does not suport the Nested case.